# Flutter repeating a Flutter method

Tags: flutter

I am wanting to repeat the handleImages() method every five seconds but having an issue getting this to work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CameraImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraImageWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraImageWidgetState createState() => _CameraImageWidgetState();
}

class _CameraImageWidgetState extends State<CameraImageWidget> {
  String handleImages() {
    List<String> cameraImages = [
      'assets/images/imageUpload.gif',
      'assets/images/imageUploadGreen.gif',
    ];
    String randomImage = (cameraImages..shuffle()).first;
    return randomImage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.asset(handleImages(), height: 450.0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Have not tested it tho.

```
class _CameraImageWidgetState extends State<CameraImageWidget> {
  String _image;

  @override
  initState(){
      handleImages();
  }
  void handleImages() async{
    List<String> cameraImages = [
      'assets/images/imageUpload.gif',
      'assets/images/imageUploadGreen.gif',
    ];
    setState(() {
       _image = (cameraImages..shuffle()).first;      
    });

    //Wait 5 seconds
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:5));
    handleImages();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.asset(_image, height: 450.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks now I am getting an overflow error of 100,000 pixels

Answer (score 0):

I made a dartpad.dev of the following code so that you can run it yourself. (however, instead of images, I am just showing the "asset text" every 5 seconds since it's on dartpad. You would just have to insert the text into the Image.asset using `Image.asset(randomImage, height: 450.0);`

Here's the dartpad: http://dartpad.dev/2af9c2d7c4b3436dfa55348bb4fb9dca

and here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CameraImageWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class CameraImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraImageWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraImageWidgetState createState() => _CameraImageWidgetState();
}

class _CameraImageWidgetState extends State<CameraImageWidget> {
  static List<String> cameraImages = [
    'assets/images/imageUpload.gif',
    'assets/images/imageUploadGreen.gif',
  ];
  String randomImage = (cameraImages..shuffle()).first;
  int count = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    handleImages();
  }

  handleImages() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        randomImage = (cameraImages..shuffle()).first;
        print(randomImage);
        count++;
        print(count);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//     return Image.asset(handleImages(), height: 450.0);
    return Text(randomImage); //
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm am getting this overflow error of 100,00 pixel.

Comment: that overflow is a layout issue.  Try reducing your image size to 350.0  (450.0 - 100)  But this is a separate issue

Comment: That might be because of the value of "initial" that I gave the first go round.  Replace this "String randomImage = "initial"; // you could make this random as well." with "String randomImage = (cameraImages..shuffle()).first;" (I'll update my code above and in the dartpad)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to select this answer as the final answer and/or upvote it? I'd appreciate it a lot since I'm trying to build up reputation points.

Comment: absolutely will do.

Comment: Would you mind selecting this answer as the final answer? and / upvote it?  Sorry to ask again.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  If so, I'd greatly appreciate if you'd select the answer and give my answer an upvote. if not, please let me know how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CameraImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraImageWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraImageWidgetState createState() => _CameraImageWidgetState();
}

class _CameraImageWidgetState extends State<CameraImageWidget> {
  String handleImages() {
    String chosenImage;
    List<String> cameraImages = [
      'assets/images/imageUpload.gif',
      'assets/images/imageUploadGreen.gif',
    ];
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
      setState(
        () {
          chosenImage = (cameraImages..shuffle()).first;
        },
      );
    });
    return chosenImage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.asset(handleImages(), height: 400.0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This code has a serious flaw.  Since the periodic timer is inside of handleImages() every time that the code updates (every 5 seconds) you'll instantiate more and more periodic timers. This code is inherently unstable.  The periodic timer should only be called once.